# Selenium automation script for <input>tag working as select tag (drop down) with checkbox in it for multiple selection?

Tags: selenium, webdriver

Can anybody help me to find a solution on here

[image]

Selenium automation script for `<input>` tag working as select tag (drop down) with checkbox in it for multiple selection.

The values selected are reading from excel file. Please find below code trial :

```
    List<WebElement> elements = (List<WebElement>) driver
            .findElements(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rcbClinicians_Input"));
    int numberOfElements = elements.size();
    System.out.println("----size----- " + numberOfElements);
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++) {
        System.out.println(i);
        elements = driver.findElements(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rcbClinicians_Input"));
        elements.get(i).click();
    }
```

Please help me find a solution

```
     <li>Choose Clincians* </li>
                        <li>
                            <div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rcbClinicians" class="RadComboBox RadComboBox_Default" style="width:500px;white-space:normal;">
    <table summary="combobox" style="border-width:0;border-collapse:collapse;width:100%" class="rcbFocused">
        <tbody><tr>
            <td style="width:100%;" class="rcbInputCell rcbInputCellLeft"><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$rcbClinicians" type="text" class="rcbInput" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rcbClinicians_Input" value="" autocomplete="off"></td>
            <td class="rcbArrowCell rcbArrowCellRight"><a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rcbClinicians_Arrow" style="overflow: hidden;display: block;position: relative;outline: none;">select</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody></table>
    <input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rcbClinicians_ClientState" name="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rcbClinicians_ClientState" type="hidden" autocomplete="off" value="{&quot;logEntries&quot;:[],&quot;value&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;text&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;enabled&quot;:true,&quot;checkedIndices&quot;:[],&quot;checkedItemsTextOverflows&quot;:false}">
</div>
                        </li>


                    </ul>
                       <ul>
                        <li>Choose CaseManagers* </li>
                        <li>
                            <div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rcbCaseManagers" class="RadComboBox RadComboBox_Default" style="width:500px;white-space:normal;">
    <table summary="combobox" style="border-width:0;border-collapse:collapse;width:100%" class="">
        <tbody><tr>
            <td style="width:100%;" class="rcbInputCell rcbInputCellLeft"><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$rcbCaseManagers" type="text" class="rcbInput" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rcbCaseManagers_Input" value="" autocomplete="off"></td>
            <td class="rcbArrowCell rcbArrowCellRight"><a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rcbCaseManagers_Arrow" style="overflow: hidden;display: block;position: relative;outline: none;">select</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody></table>
    <input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rcbCaseManagers_ClientState" name="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rcbCaseManagers_ClientState" type="hidden" autocomplete="off" value="{&quot;logEntries&quot;:[],&quot;value&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;text&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;enabled&quot;:true,&quot;checkedIndices&quot;:[],&quot;checkedItemsTextOverflows&quot;:false}">
</div>
                        </li>


                    </ul>
```

Comment: Can you show what you have tried

Comment: what error you are getting

Comment: share html code

Comment: @reshmianeesh, Can you clear out what you want to achieve ?

Comment: I need to select multiple checkboxes that are displaying on the drop downlist via reading data from excel.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything in your code that you are reading values from Excel. if you want to select value one by one yu can call this below method n time witch the the value you want to select. If you want multiple selection you can modify it with a for loop to do so.

```
    /**
 * @author mbn217
 * @Date ------
 * @Purpose This method will select a element from a list of
 * values by the name passed in the parameter
 * @param element --> element of the webpage (the weblist element)
 * @param Name --> The value we want to select
 * @return N/A
 */
public static void selectElementByName(WebElement element, String Name) {
    Select selectitem = new Select(element);
    selectitem.selectByVisibleText(Name);
}
```

Comment: Actually it is not a <select> tag. i have to Automate Combo Box (input+ checkbox) using Selenium